# Do I need to use a weapon in order to level it, or simply equip it?

Tags: warframe

I've noticed several times that weapons I have equipped, but not using at that moment, will level up when I get a kill or complete an objective. (My secondary will level up when I get a kill with my primary and vice versa).

So do all of my weapons level up at the same rate once I have them equipped for a mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you complete the mission and kill enemies.

Affinity (the exp used to level up weapons) is split amongst all your equipped items. When killing an enemy with a weapon 50% of the the affinity goes to the weapon used and 50% to your warframe. You also gain affinity when a nearby ally gains affinity, 25% of the gained affinity goes to your warframe and 75% is split evenly amongst the rest of your equipment. You can read the full rules regarding affinity [here](https://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity).

Comment: If you are using a mastered Warframe or weapon, is the affinity that it would've gained lost/wasted or redistributed?

Comment: @Yuuki Lost.  It's the reason that people tend to unequip other weapons when they're trying to level up a specific one.

Comment: Arguably a spoiler, but once you complete The War Within, you'll be able to add focus lenses to your max-rank weapons and warframes to convert some of that "lost" affinity into focus.